# iPhone 8 - Camera, Sound and Flashlight not working

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 8's camera, flashlight, and sound suddenly stopped working (I believe it was due to the update to iOS 15 or 15.0.2, but I'm not sure).

Today I didn't wake up on time because my alarm didn't make any sound. (If my iPhone is connected to my Bose Bluetooth headphone though, the sound works.)

My camera screen is completely black and when I click on the button to take a photo, record a video, and so on, it has no effect.

I literally haven't done anything suspicious on my iPhone that could lead to that, didn't drop it on the floor... anything. So if I had to guess I would say it was due to the update to iOS 15 or 15.0.2.

Any troubleshooting steps I should take?

Comment: Did you restart your iPhone?

Comment: Hi @IconDaemon ! Yes, I did Restart and also clicked on "Reset All Setting".